# React on remote server

Tags: reactjs, remote-server

I am working on a React app and trying to find a way to have it served from a local network server while I work on it, instead of localhost:3000.
The app files would be in a shared directory on the server so I could work on them from my machine. But when I npm start, the app would be accessible from the LAN and from the outside via the server.

The goal is to avoid having to build/deploy every time someone else needs to have a look at the app (which is often).

Is that even possible ?

Comment: Use the lan ip example 192.168.0.1:3000

Comment: You can use the local IP address of your computer in your network, as @cristiancamilocedeñogallego suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using VS Code you can use the [Remote Development Extension Pack](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) to SSH into the local network server and mount the workspace accordingly. You just need to setup the remote host (or subsequent ssh-exposed container) as an SSH server.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using https://ngrok.com/. After you install it, `npm start` your react app and in another terminal type `ngrok http 3000`, it will then provide you with external public facing urls anyone can access.

[image]

Comment: Let me give you an early heads-up: we [require disclosure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when promoting your own services. It’s fine if you want to put your screen sharing service *in your profile* but it doesn’t belong in answers (or comments, but your colleague has probably already told you this).

Comment: i did read the initial email you sent. i did disclose the I work as an expert on Hopps. what am I missing in terms of disclosure? the guidelines are a bit vague so I think I will just find other avenues for promotion. sorry Martijn